# Fetch posts starting with alphabet [x]

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

```
<?php $temp_query = $wp_query; ?>
<?php query_posts('tag=sometag,anothertag&posts_per_page=10'); ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  // print post here
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php $wp_query = $temp_query; ?>
```

Using this simple wordpress loop, how do I show ONLY the posts (post titles actually) starting with say letter 'G'. I want to sort posts alphabetically but only those that matches, not all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would set up an action for the query. In your themes functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'posts_where', 'startswithaction' );
function startswithaction( $sql ){
    global $wpdb;
    $startswith = get_query_var( 'startswith' );

    if( $startswith ){
        $sql .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE %s ", $startswith.'%' );
    }

    return $sql;
}
```

Then you can query the posts like so:

```
query_posts( 'startswith=G&posts_per_page=10' );
```

Comment: You just taught me something VERY valuable, thank you. I had no idea up until 5 seconds ago that the 'posts_where' action existed. :D

Comment: This is a very nice solution, but I personally don't like using raw SQL anywhere. It's strange that the basic query post parameters don't have something like the meta queries on posts has regarding 'LIKE', 'NOT LIKE, ect. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Answer (score 3):

Check the post title inside the loop:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    // jump to the next post if this one doesn't start with the letter you want
    if($post->post_title[0] != $letter) continue

    // do what you want with the post
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Crazy thought here, but why dont you just add the Letter as a Tag to the post. In other words, if you wanted your post "The Beautiful Trees" to show up under "B" (note that I said B and not T), simply apply the tag called "B". Then in you query posts tag section, just make sure you append your letter of choice!